# .net / python utility/library that will give a screenshot of a directory structure

Tags: c#, .net, python, directory

does anyone know if there exists a library that will give a snapshot image of a directory structure ?

if not, is there an easy programming approach to creating this in c# or python?

Comment: Just "indent" for the directory contents, and "dedent" when done.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'snapshot image'? Are you looking for a screenshot of Windows Explorer or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
import os, sys

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    full_path = os.path.abspath(root)
    chunks = full_path.split(os.path.sep)
    depth = len(chunks) - 2
    indent = '  ' * depth
    print indent + full_path
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "snapshot image" of a directory structure, but it is likely that you can do what you need rather easily.

For example, in Python, the os.walk can be used to navigate a directory of your choice.

```
import os
rootdir='C:\path\to\directory'

def parseobj(parent, tab):
    for child in parent:
        if type(child) == list: 
            tab = tab + 1
            parseobj(child, tab)
        else:
            for t in range(0,tab): print '\t',
            print '\\',
            print child

for obj in os.walk(rootdir): 
    tab = 0
    if type(obj) == tuple:
        parseobj(obj, tab)
    else:
        print obj
```